# jenkins canot cannot pass parameters to the remote server's shell script with 'publish over ssh' plugin

Tags: jenkins

I executed a shell script command from the remote server via Jenkins and wanted to pass a defined environment variable.
my test pipeline script  as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        param = "param1"
    }
    stages{
        stage('deploy project') {
            steps {
                sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: '192.168.1.112-ssh',
                transfers: [sshTransfer(cleanRemote: true,
                execCommand: '''
                    /root/test.sh hello ${param} world ${JOB_NAME}
                ''',
                execTimeout: 120000, patternSeparator: '[, ]+',remoteDirectory: '/',
                removePrefix: '', sourceFiles: '')])])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the remote script 'test.sh' are as follows

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$@"
```

then,The jenkins console builds are logged as follows

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (deploy project)
[Pipeline] step
SSH: Connecting from host [2a132d40d769]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [192.168.1.112-ssh] ...
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [
                    /root/test.sh hello ${param} world pipeline-docker-demo
                ] ...
hello
world
hello world pipeline-docker-demo
SSH: EXEC: completed after 207 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [192.168.1.112-ssh] ...
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

You find that we can only pass one jenkins built-in variable with **'${JOB_NAME}'** and not the variable defined in this script with **'${param}'**

**my app version:**

- jenkins:2.235.2
- the plugin 'Publish Over SSH': '1.20.1'

What do I have to do to pass this custom variable，please help me,thanks a lot.

Comment: problem was solved，notify:
<code>
execCommand: '''
                    /root/test.sh hello ${param} world ${JOB_NAME}
                ''
</code>'
change to
<code>
execCommand: """
                    /root/test.sh hello ${param} world ${JOB_NAME}
                """</code>